# Setting up IPv6 connection on iPhone from Mac book pro (El Capitan)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipv6, ipv4

Apple rejected my app since it failed to do few functionalities on IPv6 connections. I have to test the app. I have a broadband connection of IPv4. I created a NAT64 connection in Network Sharing on my Mac book. I connected my device wirelessly to it. The device shows it has an IPv6 address. However I do not get any internet access to test my app . 
[This is how I created a NAT64 connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3j3l.png)

Comment: I have created NAT64 in the same way and its working,.,are you able to connect to this new wifi from your phone?

Comment: btw, If you have all server call with Domain name and not with ip address, there should not be any issue with  ipv6 on iPhone.  My app was rejected for similar result and I realize that I was using netadderss for checking connectivity through reachability.

Comment: Reachability tests are not always a good idea, they might give you the wrong answer. Better to just try to connect and handle any failures. You need to do that anyway.

Comment: @iOS_devloper, yea I am able to connect to the wifi from my mobile. But i am not getting internet access.

Comment: @SanderSteffann but the in-app purchases is what the the app review team told me is not working in IPv6.

Comment: Did you share to the correct USB-Ethernet adapter? You seem to have two of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yea I connected to correct USB-Ethernet (USB 2.0...). That one is getting only when i connect that the usb cable.